# Simple PayPal connection with Craft?

Tags: payment-methods

I'm creating a simple site where the user can buy exactly 1 product for exactly 1 price. My client wants to offer PayPal to the users for paying this product.

Which solution/plugin/whatever do you propose? Commerce seems to be a bit too big for this, I don't have lots of products with specifications, etc. But I didn't find any other plugin that can handle PayPal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on your requirements, but seems like you'd just be able to use the standard PayPal checkout button for this, no?

https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/paypal-payments-standard